# Get div position (top) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One div i set the height in css using `top:-26px;`. I have other divs other places where i'd like to align with that div. I notice in jquery writing `.css('top')` gets me my css and not the y coord of the div. How do i get the absolute x,y position using javascript?

Comment: plz write your first div css to help others for answer.

Answer (score 17):

I will give you the vanilla solution.. don't complain.. add a [0] to your element and it's fixed! :P hope this helps.

```
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
var x = getOffset( document.getElementById('yourElId') ).left;
```

Comment: top gets me -18 :(. I need the absolute position and this position is relative.

Comment: Maybe you can try showing us your HTML and CSS.... might be a bit more helpful then.

Comment: Have a look .........http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm

Comment: @Larrykuk I don't understand what I'm supposed to be looking at?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `jQuery(element).offset().top`

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about JQuery, and your code should be rewritten with `jQuery(element).offset().top`.

Comment: @VisioN: What are you talking about i did mention jquery. Well, kind of (.css function is not straight js) +0. It doesnt work and its `.offset().top` (i had to look both up)

Comment: top gets me -18 :(. I need the absolute position and this position is relative.

Comment: @acidzombie24 no offset gives you the absolute position.... read the docs and the code...

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
function getElementPosition(id) {
    var offsetTrail = document.getElementById(id);
    var offsetLeft = 0;
    var offsetTop = 0;
    while (offsetTrail) {
        offsetLeft += offsetTrail.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop += offsetTrail.offsetTop;
        offsetTrail = offsetTrail.offsetParent;
    }

    return {
        left: offsetLeft,
        top: offsetTop
    };
}​
```

It will return an object with `left` and `top` variables.

If you use JQuery try [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method:

```
var pos = $("#element").offset();
console.log(pos.left)
console.log(pos.top)
```

Comment: same problem with the others. Top gets me -18 :(. I need the absolute position and this position is relative.

Comment: @acidzombie24 Are you sure that you don't mix absolute and relative positions? These functions return position of the element relative to the page.

Comment: @VisioN I already noted that offsetTop is relative to him... wait and maybe some CSS or HTML will shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Cross browser safe down to IE 8, possibly even 7 or 6:

```
function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}
var offsetEl = offset(document.getElementById('some_id'));
console.log(offsetEl.left, offsetEl.top);
```

Short and fast and no jQuery needed.

Comment: Simon, where a function getBoundingClientRect? you copy other website? wtf lol

Comment: No idea what your problem is and don't care. Here's a reference for this method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: hum.. Mozilla? its no know, ur post about IE8... too confused .... test in http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/sj6tnfce/2/

Answer (score 0):

With standard JavaScript:

```
var elem=document.getElementById("elemID");
var top=elem.offsetTop;
var left=elem.offsetLeft;
```

With jQuery:

```
var top=$("#elemID").offset().top;
var left=$("#elemID").offset().left;
```

Comment: offsetTop returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node. not the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery(element).offset()

Hope it helps.

For example

```
var elementPosition = jQuery(element).offset();
var elementTopPositon = elementPosition.top;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var MyElement = document.getElementById("...Your_DIV_Control...");
>
> var top = MyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
> ```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.