# Angular5 - get distance of directive/component to top and left

Tags: css, angular

I have a component with the following template (...component.html):

`<canvas></canvas>`

Furthermore I have in ...component.ts:

```
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas')
  private canvasRef: ElementRef;
```

How can I now calculate the to the window border as marked in the picture below (see red lines)?

[image]

For jQuery users: I'm looking for a way to calculate `$("#desiredCanvasElement").position();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564680/get-div-position-top-in-javascript

Comment: @mr.void using jQuery is fine for me. Just don't know how to use the `canvasRef` property together with jQuery

Comment: just do $(canvasRef) , ensure jquery is loaded

Comment: just `$(canvasRef) ` leads to an error, `$(this.canvasRef.nativeElement)` works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef):

```
class ElementRef {
  constructor(nativeElement: any)
  nativeElement: any
}
```

Solution:

`$(this.canvasRef.nativeElement).position()`

Answer (score 1):

Heres a no jquery solution I think

If I am understanding your question correctly,couldn't you use client heights?

```
@ViewChild('canvasContainer')
private canvasContainerRef: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('canvas')
private canvasRef: ElementRef;

verticalBorderHeight: number = 0;
horizontalBorderHeight: number = 0;

ngAfterViewInit() { //Or whatever lifecycle event you want to use to check the heights 
    this.verticalBorderHeight = (this.canvasContainerRef.nativeElement.clientHeight - this.canvasRef.nativeElement.clientHeight) / 2;
    this.horizontalBorderHeight = (this.canvasContainerRef.nativeElement.clientWidth - this.canvasRef.nativeElement.clientWidth) / 2;
}
```

Here a "working" example
https://embed.plnkr.co/N3Z8Bi7vrNlCYEfzI4En/

Comment: This doesn't work, since the padding is part of the element itself (as you use it in your fiddle). If you change padding to margin (which is an example for my usecase) your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough, but the same methodology should work, no?